# Update Style attribute at runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, runtime

I set colors for my Application in Style.xml file:

```
<style name="Theme1" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:Background">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

I can update Background color at runtime like:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

So my requirement is to update style.xml file at runtime not hard coding it in java code. Is there a way to update attribute of style xml permanently at runtime like:

```
<item name="android:Background">#FFF</item>
```

To:

```
<item name="android:Background">#FF00FF00</item>
```

Comment: I just give the idea, and its not matter which object just want to edit attribute of style at runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```

Comment: This will change the textview style to bold, i can do this but the issue is that there are several textview and other objects. If i do it your way then i have to initialize all objects first and set them one by one. Please read my question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Well its impossible to change style.xml at runtime because xml file complies into package. I found a way by creating a json file and saving it in external or internal space. And at runtime its much easier to update json/xml file.